# Constraints in custom tables for plugin development - Yes or No?

Tags: plugin-development

After a longer web search, I still don't know, whether I should use constraints in my custom tables for WordPress plugin development. The most of my custom tables have a relation to the {prefix}users table with a foreign key user_id referring to the ID of {prefix}users. In common database design I would make a sql query like this example:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `{prefix}logs` (
`user_id` INT UNSIGNED  NOT NULL,
[...]
PRIMARY KEY  (`user_id`),
CONSTRAINT `logs_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
REFERENCES `{prefix}users` (`ID`)
ON UPDATE CASCADE 
ON DELETE CASCADE)
CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

For WordPress don't make use of constraints due to the specific database design of WordPress core, I'm not sure whether to use for my plugin or not.

Comment: I don't think there is a right or wrong answer here, you're likely to mostly just get opinions, which is a problem as you need to be able to mark an answer as the canonically concretely correct answer for all people in this situation. The reassurance of the "right way to do it" simply doesn't exist. As an aside, have you considered abandoning the table entirely and using user meta/taxonomies instead? You may also find the `dbdelta` WP function useful

Comment: All my concerning custom tables have 1:n relations (one user to many ...) and I need to query them. An option would be using custom post types, but except for one entity it makes no sense in this case. I think it is always better to use constraints in database design, so I would like to use them in my tables, unless some one here would have good arguments not to do it.

Comment: As far as custom tables go, there's really little WP-centric advice or guidelines to go off of, and no framework to hang things off of. It's 99.999% the same as if it was a generic PHP script except perhaps using the `wpdb` class instead of `mysqli` to do your queries. You still have to build all the UI, all the caching layer, write all the queries etc yourself. If constraints works and works well for you then hooray, but otherwise I very much doubt that anybody could say anything WP related that would impact your decision in any way. There are no WP things that are for or against constraints